# Loss of display and Vino in previously working system

Tags: display, vino

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system which crashed due to a hardware failure in the UPS.

Normally I access it remotely using SSH and VNC but I had to connect a monitor to confirm the BIOS settings and I noticed that the display only worked up until the Ubuntu splash screen. After that, the monitor was still receiving a signal but was black with a cursor occasionally appearing top left. I was still able to see the screen using VNC. I tried another reboot but that killed Vino and I just got an error trying to restart it. I can still SSH ok but the vino server won't start.

There are two GPUs in the PC: the internal Intel GPU and an NVidia GT610. I've tried swapping from one to the other in the BIOS but they both show the same symptoms.

I tried:

```
sudo /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --display=:0.0

No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display: :0.0
```

I tried upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 but it failed while trying to update the NVidia driver (which I reported) and so I'm still on 20.04. (Note: the upgrade failed here, i.e. it aborted.)

So: how do I get both the physical display (with either GPU) and vino to work? And what could cause the display to suddenly fail in this way?

I have had this happen before, about 2 years ago and I had to do a fresh install to fix it. I'd prefer not to have to do that again.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh install of 22.02. Still having intermittent display issues. After a reboot, the local monitor works and VNC works. But if I disconnect the monitor (which is what I want to do as the PC is going to be run headless most of the time), VNC stops working and there's no display on the monitor if I reconnect it.

Update: I've been told swapping between running with a physical monitor and running headless can cause problems similar to the ones I experienced. The solution is to use a dummy HDMI plug.